# CSS Equal Height for DT and DD

Tags: html, css, list, height

I am trying to style a description list `<dl>` so that they appear as two columns even when there are multiple `<dd>`s following the `<dt>`. The problem is that I want it to be dynamic so no floating the `<dt>` and then setting a margin on the `<dd>`s.

```
<dl>
  <dd>Term A</dd>
  <dt>Definition A1</dt>
  <dt>Definition A2</dt>
  <dd>Term B</dd>
  <dt>Definition B1</dt>
</dl>
```

Normally I would use one of the many solutions out there for making two equal height columns but I don't have a container element to use here so it kinda threw me off. Any suggestions?

Updated with [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zpwnsjk/)

Comment: i would probably use table instead using `dd` `dt`

Comment: For clarification, this is what I want it to look like: http://i.imgur.com/ehEExdg.png without specifying widths.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. hope it will be helpful.

```
dl {
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:#ff0;
}
dd, dt {
 float: left;
 width:20%; /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
 background:#dd0;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 line-height: 250%;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7aL4ry3s/)**

**[Check it our this blog too](http://twobanjos.com/blog/2009/06/5-ways-to-style-dl/)**